# Hide link target in exported agenda HTML views?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

If I export a standard agenda view ("a") to HTML, all links are displayed like this:

```
_Incoming:                   Search [[https://google.com][Google]]
```

But I would prefer that only the descriptive text be shown, like this:

```
_Incoming:                   Search Google
```

Is this possible?

Below is the HTML source code that is generated, indented for easier reading. Note how the link is broken up into multiple sections as well.

```
<span class="org-scheduled-today">_Incoming:                  </span>
<span class="org-todo">TODO</span>
<span class="org-scheduled-today"> Search </span>
<span class="org-scheduled-today">
  <span class="org-link">
    <a href="https://google.com">[[https://google.com]</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">[</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Googl</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">e</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">]</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">]</a>
  </span>
</span>
```

The original headline is:

```
* TODO Search [[https://google.com][Google]]
SCHEDULED: <2022-11-04 Fri>
```

Comment: I think that `htmlize.el` somehow mishandles that link. If I export the agenda to `foo.txt` it looks fine; if I then `M-x htmlize-buffer` I get the mangled link. I would post a query to the Org mode mailing list (referencing this question): there may be an option to just use the description (but it seems to me that that defeats the purpose of saving to HTML in the first place - just IMHO). I suspect however that you will need to open an issue in the [emacs-htmlize](https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize) repo.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize/issues/25) issue may (or may not) be related.